# Как прокрутить Panel через AutoScroll широким шагом?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите как прокрутить Panel (роликом мыши) через AutoScroll широким шагом, чтобы ширина Panel делилась на две части. К примеру ширина Panel до сужения равна 800 точек, и должна поделиться на 2 при прокрутке. Чтобы в сжатом состоянии на 400 точек, сразу попадать на вторую часть Panel

Растянутое состояние (для добавления чекбоксов)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сжатое состояние (какими должны быть размеры приложения) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задайте скроллбару свойства `SmallChange`, `LargeChange`.

Comment: Спасибо, но как обратиться к AutoScroll если он считает себя всей панелью? Обратиться напрямую к панели прокрутки нельзя...

Comment: У панели есть свойства `HorizontalScroll`, `VerticalScroll`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
private void Panel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var stepLength = panel1.Width;
    if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        if (panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value + stepLength < panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
        {
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value += stepLength;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
        }
    }
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        if (panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value - stepLength > panel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum)
        {
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value -= stepLength;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum;
        }
    }
}
```

Будет лишний скролл в конце/начале прокрутки если соотношение будет не ровно 2, а, например, 2.1

Comment: Спасибо, но я все пытаюсь роликом сделать большой шаг ползунка, чтобы ползунок передвигался пополам всей суженной длины панели. Прокрутил ролик мыши 1 раз, ползунок оказался на середине, прокрутил второй раз, ползунок оказался в конце, и так же наоборот.

Comment: Да, в этом примере именно так все и работает

Comment: Может я что-то не так делаю, но у меня при прокрутке ролика мыши, шагов нужно сделать несколько раз до середины. Вот пример: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0TQKyrVeUg

Comment: У вас очень большое расстояние между CheckBox-ами. Сейчас прокручивается ровно на размер панели. А расстояние между чекбоксами больше его. Если вы их генерите программно, то в строке определения stepLength присваивайте ему большее из значений: ширина панели и расстояние между чекбоксами.

Comment: Ну что, у вас получилось решить вашу задачу?

Comment: К сожалению нет... думаю поменять способ кнопкой